# I want to print c pattern as upper triangle

Tags: c

I want to print some C pattern for upper triagnle which sholud print numeric value  1 to 10.
Now my code is like this:-

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int j = 1, k, l, i;
    for (i = 4; i >= 1; i--) {
        for (k = i - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (l = 4; l >= i; l--) {
            printf("%2d", j);
            j++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Its output is fine but when my value reach near 10 it's space is missing.
How can I resolve it?

My output looks like

```
    1
   2 3
  4 5 6
 7 8 910
```

It should be:

```
    1
   2 3
  4 5 6
 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: Here is what to do when you get some good answers to your question [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the alignment by using the `-` sign. This makes it left-justified.

Replace

```
printf("%2d",j);
```

with

```
printf("%-2d",j);
```

[**Live demo**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jnblskOjc8bPFTVP)

If you want the bottom of the pyramid to be completely to the left with no space you can replace

```
for (k = i - 1; k >= 0; k--)
```

with

```
for (k = i - 1; k > 0; k--)
```

**EDIT:**

As [@chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4593267/chqrlie) pointed out this will leave a trailing blank space in every line except the last one, this can be fixed like:

```
//...
for (i = 4; i >= 1; i--)
{
    for (k = i - 1; k > 0; k--) // change from k >= 0 to k > 0
    {          
        printf(" ");
    }
    for (l = 4; l >= i; l--)
    {
        printf(" %d", j); // change from "%2d" to " %d"
        j++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
//...
```

[**Live demo**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OCG0bfG13xUT5mhG)

Answer (score 3):

For this problem, with `n` lines of output, you need to produce `n - i` spaces at the beginning of line `i` and `i` numbers each preceded by a space. Instead of `"%2d"`, use `" %d"` and output one less space at the start of each line. You can use `printf` to output an arbitrary number of spaces using `%*s` and an empty string.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i;      // line number
    int j = 1;  // starting number
    int n = 4;  // number of lines
    int k;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        printf("%*s", n - i, ""); // output n - i spaces
        for (k = 0; k < i; k++) {
            printf(" %d", j);
            j++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
    1
   2 3
  4 5 6
 7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved in two ways:

One way to resolve this is by simply **add spacing (padding)** for each character you are printing.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int j=1,k,l,i;
    for(i=4;i>=1;i--){
        for(k=i-1;k>=0;k--){
            printf("  ");
        }
        for(l=4;l>=i;l--){
           printf(" %2d ",j); //Padding added
                   ^   ^
           j++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Secondly you can change the **alignment by using - sign**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int j=1,k,l,i;
    for(i=4;i>=1;i--){
        for(k=i-1;k>=0;k--){
            printf("  ");
        }
        for(l=4;l>=i;l--){
           printf("-%2d",j); //Left justified
                   ^
           j++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Neither approach solves the problem: the first will produce 2 or 3 spaces between all numbers and the second is missing a space at the beginning of line.

Answer (score 1):

Amongst the other good answers, another way is to use `printf("%d ", j);` instead of `printf("%2d", j);` - Note the white space `' '` behind the `%d` format specifier. - This method has the disadvantage that you have a trailing white space after `10` but it accomplishes the (obvious) desired output:

[Online example](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qgA%2BhOSkAzpnbICeOpUy10AYVSsArgFtaIAMydSq9ABk8tTADk9AI0zEQANlIAHVNMJLamnfpGJp7einSW1na6js5usvJhtAwEzMQE/noGxjJymAq%2ByakEEbYOTq4yKWkZgdnSVcVWpdHlLgCUMqjaxMgcAOQApABMhlbIOlgA1AOG6vX4qAB0CDPYAwAMAIIbm1YEk7rMVpMQAG6oeOhtOwMA7ABCO5PPk3uTfNOGACKTJpMA1qRJqwgXgZo8ti9JjRiCc8J8ftxwa9Pmtvr9kXgALRYtrTB5PKEvGEnf4IlFYjGGe4A1EzH7rZH/HF4u4QzZEzmTdzEPZUCDDIbTIZDa7Uwmcu5fCVEkkQVjkpHU4F09Fg5WsFn49lcqE8vkCkXDACs6GFQyBfDFOt1zz4w0eQ0e4shXKlMr1vPo/MFA2N6logutMvdruexEwBG6tEmjJd21uXz6HVYID6xr6pAMfXWmdQafUk2kXR6mGFxkzBDTubaHX%2BRkMi1u6wAHC2hi2AJy3W6cTgubjrXipvrcTO6LjrdZZ6t5tOZ6QgadVnPJ0hwWAwRAoVC6dx4dhkCgQNB7g/lZDATjrExUA8EJyLiD2WekexWVIAT1fp90qgIADytCsN%2Bq6kFghyiOwr74BG%2BSnJgi5gZgAAeeTaA%2Br57HIr6sHg9jEF%2BmhYGmnCVryE6rh0ND0EwbAcDw/CCMIoggBIYhSHh9iLpAHSoO4iRIViADqbAKiJqEEIRkwie4mDoCIijIDJwlOMQJALrk%2BTKBAZg1AYJhmCUUQxIIIQ%2BHQ%2BlmV4Fm0MZZTOCY8R5IkhTVFomSCM52lJA09ktI5lRFFZTl%2BU0JnlJwHTFt0vRcCmaYZjOYH5n0KEti4WIDpMwDIMp16LJwJy4IQJDln8mhnoe5V4uolazrWpAIJgzBYM4EB1g2iwtustydv1nZDNwxrGusnZCGmY6kBOo3JbmpCpQuS6kCuNbrluEBIKh6FEEelCpMA0gAAoiHIDAIKgADu2ZkaQp77sIiQndYrDnVd2bzfd57OJe14mF9h4ARhb3Xa%2B23IJsxCHfOphocgyT4NmmY0YwLDQYxAgmCx4iSEI%2BE8R1C0Cb4SELiWcWhYjz1nRdoNURN6aZh9c5pRlWXcDleW/OshWTNgcMYWVEAlbtNWTHVK0NR0zWteUhMjlNM3TszC0w4uy5S6Q9ZDLciwjYYhguDeLa3F2w1Y2mhhM6%2Bi2S/TG7bl0BDuBh5CUADkWmPgu2CCjdHo7wl2Ee4pFriOSUq6lwzGJMl2EAgkzpZl2W5flPO3atyadYYLZNoYpvXi2hjcJ2XZ9gzU2R2ry2Z41I5DNbKUw7XHQIcQ3jKNwQA%3D)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int j = 1, k, l, i;
    for (i = 4; i >= 1; i--){
        for (k = i - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for(l = 4; l >= i; l--) {
           printf("%d ", j);
           j++;
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
    1 
   2 3 
  4 5 6 
 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: Technically, the expected output should not have trailing spaces. You should use `" %d"` and output one less space at the beginning of line.

Comment: @chqrlie Yes, I already knew that this version has this downside. Just wanted to add another solvable way, since good answers was/are already given. Yes, I like your method, but I won´t copy it. I just upvoted your answer instead.